# ons-list内で最下部までスクロールした時のイベント

Tags: ios, monaca, onsen-ui

お世話になります。
質問させてください。

monacaでonsen-uiを使用しています。
ons-list内で最下部までスクロールした時のイベントをとりたいのですが、みなさんどうやって実装していますでしょうか？
最下部までスクロール → 自動読み込み　このよくある機能を実装したいのです。

$(window).on("load scrol", hove);
ではスクロール値を取得できませんでした。
既出（ https://monaca.mobi/ja/forum/q/52ea3b8a7e2193dd37eea8d1 ）

今のところ、この機能を実装したいがためだけに、
ons-listでは無く、iscroll.jsを使用しています。

どうぞご教授くださいませ。

Answer (score 2):

1.スペルミス
    scrol→scroll

2.Onsen-UIなら以下のような感じで出来ませんか？

```js
$("#scroll_test").on("scroll", function(){
 console.log("change : "+scroll_test.scrollTop);
 //スクロール最大値　==　スクロールエリアサイズ　+　スクロール値
 if(scroll_test.scrollHeight <= scroll_test.clientHeight + scroll_test.scrollTop){console.log("scroll max");}
});
```

```html
<ons-scroller id="scroll_test" style="height: 200px; width: 100%"><ons-list>
 <ons-list-header>Header Text</ons-list-header>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
 </ons-list>
 <ons-list-header>Header Text2</ons-list-header>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Item</ons-list-item>
 </ons-list>
</ons-scroller>
```

Answer (score 1):

onsen-uiを利用しているのであれば、angularのDirectiveを使用してみるのはどうでしょうか。
右記URLにサンプルがあります。http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/